# C String Insertion Issues

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function that can insert a char array of length len into a given index in a string type. However, it acts ways that it shouldn't.

When trying to insert at the end of the initial array, the contents of `buf` are inserted at the beginning of the string, in reverse order.

i.e. inserting `world` into `Hello` becomes `dlrowHello`

When trying to insert in the middle of the initial case, the output is `worldHello`

`str->bytes.data` is the array being modified.

`str->bytes.usage` is the length of that array.

```
bool string_insert(string_t * const str, size_t index, 
        const char * const buf, size_t len)
{
    bool success = false;
    uint8_t orig_size = str->bytes.usage;
    uint8_t * temp;

    if (str->len < index){
        return false;
    }
    if(str->bytes.usage+len>=str->bytes.usage){
        temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str->bytes.usage + len));
    }   
    else {
        temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str->bytes.usage));
    }
    if (temp == NULL){
        success = false;    
    }
    else{
        if (index == 0){  //inserts at beginning

            for (int k = 0; k < len; k++){
                temp[k] = buf[k];

            }   
            for (int j = len; j < str->bytes.usage+len; j++){
                temp[j] = str->bytes.data[j - len];
            }
        }
        else if (index == str->bytes.usage){    //inserts at end
            for (int h = 0; h < str->bytes.usage; h++){
                temp[h] = str->bytes.data[h];
            }
            for (int g = 0; g < len; g++){
                temp[g+str->bytes.usage] = buf[g];  
            }

        }
        else{    //inserts in the middle
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                temp[i] = str->bytes.data[i];
            }
            for(int i = index; i < index + len; i++){
                temp[i] = buf[i-index];
            }
            for(int i = index + len; i < str->bytes.usage+len; i++){
                temp[i] = str->bytes.data[i-len];
            }
        }
        string_free(str);
        str->bytes.data = temp;
        str->bytes.dim = 2*str->bytes.usage;
        str->bytes.usage = orig_size+len;
        success = true;
    }
        return success;
}
```

Basically, I just need to know if I'm blind and missing something obvious.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including structure definitions and how you call the function.

Comment: Also, you should learn how to use a debugger, then you can step through the code line by line to see what's actually happening.

Comment: The code looks fine except for that the strings are not 0 terminated. Is that by design?

Comment: I forgot to consider that, I'll give it a test.

Comment: Debugger..........DCV

Comment: Some memory is being malloc'd but never an indication returned to the caller.  Nor is that malloc'd memory being passed to free().   So this code has a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

When index is 0, it is not in reverse order?

```
if (index == 0){  //inserts at beginning of array

            for (int k = 0; k < len; k++){
                temp[k] = buf[k];
```

changed to

```
if (index == 0){  //inserts at beginning of array

     for (int k = 0; k < len; k++){
            temp[k] = buf[len - k - 1];
```

Comment: When it intentionally inserts at the beginning, it works fine. However, when it tries to insert at the end, it inserts backwards at the beginning

Comment: It's the position where the char array is inserted, so index = 0 is the beginning and str->bytes.usage is the end, and anything else is in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

```
// as i understand it:
// str->bytes.data = allocated memory
// str->bytes.dim  = size of the allocated memory
// str->bytes.usage= size of the used memory
//

#define BLOCK_SIZE  32

bool string_insert(string_t * const str, size_t index, 
        const char *  buf, size_t len)
{
    int max_size;
    int i;
    char *start;
    char *end;
    char *tmp=str->bytes.data;

    max_size=str->bytes.usage+len;


    if(max_size>=str->bytes.dim){
        // realloc by BLOCK_SIZE steps
        max_size=((max_size/BLOCK_SIZE)+1)*BLOCK_SIZE;
        tmp=realloc(tmp,max_size); 
        if(!tmp) return 0; //false

        //update fields with new values
        str->bytes.data=tmp;
        str->bytes.dim=max_size;
    }


    start=tmp+index;
    end=tmp+(str->bytes.usage);

    //shift content after the insertion point
    while(end>start){
        end--;
        *(end+len)=*end;
    }

    // no comments
    strncpy (start,buf,len);

    str->bytes.usage+=len;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the posted convolutions, you could try something similar to this

Assuming:

1. Not normal C strings
2. the string_t instances do not contain enough unused memory to
   hold both the strings
3. string 2 is to be inserted at the offset into string 1
4. the string_t is defined as:

   typedef struct
   {
       char * pStr;
       int    strLen;
   } string_t;

caveat: not compiled, nor tested

```
string_t *string_insert( 
    const string_t * originalStr, 
    const string_t * strToInsert, 
    size_t index )
{

    string_t  *newString = NULL;

    if( NULL != (newString =  malloc( sizeof( string_t )) ) )
    { // then malloc successful
        newString->pStr = NULL;
        newString->strLen = 0;

        // allocate enough room.
        if(NULL != (newString->pStr = 
                    malloc( originalStr->strlen + strToInsert->strlen )
        {// then mallooc successful
            newString->strLen = 
                origianlStr->strlen + strToInsert->strLen;

            //copy first part of originalStr to newString
            for( int i = 0; i < index; i++ )
            {
                newString->pStr[i] = originalStr->pStr[i];
            }

            // copy string to insert
            for( int j=0; j<strToInsert->strlen; j++ )
            {
                newStr->pStr[i+j] = strToInsert-pStr[j];
            }

            // copy last part of originalStr to newStr
            for ( int k = 0; k<newString->strLen; k++ )
            {
                newStr->pStr[i+j+k] = origianalStr->pStr[index+k];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            free( newString );
            newString = NULL;
        }
    }

    return newString
} // end function: string_insert
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
    if (str->len < index){
```

, but you fail to assign anything to `str->len`.